# Filter entries by more than one categories

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I have lot of entries with many category groups.
The template first show all entries, after by selecting a category the url became like this

```
http://local.site.ext/all/category/category_name
```

How can I specify a second category to filter more the entries and how url will be?

Comment: I'd look to Low's Seg2Cat addon for this:
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat

Your urls can be local.site.ext/template_name/category1/category2 etc.